# git push origin master does nothing, prompts for user and pass then, nothing

Tags: git, push

I have tried, resetting the git url, it worked a couple hours ago, I have no idea what's going on, I can change, commit, but when I push it prompts me for the user and pass, then nothing

```
redklouds@RedKloudsCenter:~/docker/dockertutorial$ vim app.py
redklouds@RedKloudsCenter:~/docker/dockertutorial$ git add .
redklouds@RedKloudsCenter:~/docker/dockertutorial$ git commit -m 'daf'
[master aa7ba15] daf
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
redklouds@RedKloudsCenter:~/docker/dockertutorial$ git push -f origin master  

Username for 'https://github.com': redklouds
Password for 'https://redklouds@github.com':
redklouds@RedKloudsCenter:~/docker/dockertutorial$
```

Here is my config file

```
eredklouds@RedKloudsCenter:~/docker/dockertutorial$ cat .git/config
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/redklouds/cicd-flaskapp.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
redklouds@RedKloudsCenter:~/docker/dockertutorial$
```

Comment: Can you please check with the command **git remote -v** This shows whether the remote branch for fetch and push is assigned properly or not

Comment: You can also add the `--verbose` flag to your `push` command to get more information